# What style/type of storm door handle and lock is this?

Tags: doors, lock, storm-door

This storm door handle has gone bad and needs replaced. With my experience in the past, these handle sets are very specific styles, and not something I can just go to a big box store and find a replacement. This is a single exterior handle with a separate deadbolt and handle on the interior. I *think* the deadbolt being separate than the handle could probably remain, but if it's a set I'll just buy the entire replacement. Ordinarily I'd try to find door manufacture information and go from there, but this door appears to be quite old and can't find it. Does anyone know what type of handle set I need here to replace this setup?

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with it?  There isn't that much that can go wrong.  The outside handle is connected to the inside one, probably with a flat pin, and maybe there's a set screw that fell out resulting in its drooping like that.  Probably easier to fix it.  To replace without knowing the make/model you can buy replacements and the main thing you'll need is the distance between the handle and deadbolt.

Comment: Use a mirror to look on the top/bottom edges of the door for a label or nameplate that might  ID the manufacturer.

Comment: That says "Larson" to my eyes. https://www.pinterest.com/pin/351562314639212520/?d=t&mt=login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to track this down via Storm Door Parts Warehouse. Apparently this is a 'Larson 356' series style door. This handle and lock setup is unusual to me as most have the door latch on the side of the door internally, but hopefully this helps someone in the future if they come across it as well: https://stormdoorpartswarehouse.com/bright-brass-outside-with-color-match-inside-handle-kit/

Comment: Thanks for coming back to update us!